# Не рендеряться компонент в собранном index.html. Webpack4

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Делаю проект на react/redux. Проект собирается, все скрипты подключаются, на dev-server'e все работает как надо.
Но почему то в итоговом index.html ничего не рендериться.

Монтирую это:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Сюда:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте `HashRouter` вместо `BrowserRouter`

ссылка на описание [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)